# JavaScript - Vue - POST request before browser exits

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In 2017, for browsers updated to this point as of October 2017, is there a way to send a POST request before the browser exits? I'd like to send a POST request so that the application knows when (or if) it was abandoned midway.

If not, is there a better way to check when a user is connected and then send a POST request?

I am using Vue 2.4, if that helps.

I know there have been [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824125/alert-before-page-close-how-to-change-the-chromes-default-message#comment66800425_37874651) to this but the old ones do not work as Chrome have updated their engine.

Comment: Checking when a user connects is relatively simple if your app has any sort of authentication step.

Comment: @MikeC I suppose I can make each user connect through a NodeJS app and check their heartbeat and if no response in x seconds.. disconnect and "finish their app". But I'd rather not introduce another layer of complexity... if I do not have to.

Comment: Sadly, as far as i know, there is no safe method to perform any request before closing the window and using ping every x seconds is the only reliable approach.